# Is my PCB ready for PWM solenoid control?

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design, esp32, solenoid

I am looking to upgrade my project to handle "back EMF" from solenoids when used in PWM mode in combination with MOSFET.
The original project lives on a breadboard, and I am attempting to design a PCB.

[image: PCB schematic]

[ESP32-C6-WROOM-1 datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/891/Espressif_ESP32_C6_WROOM_1__Datasheet_V0_1_PRELIMI-3239987.pdf)
[IRLB8721PbF datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/b69003e9a3061f81b201d4c8f0c01a07/irlb8721pbf.pdf)

**Are there any mistakes in the design regarding**:

- powering ESP32 from IN1(it should power ESP32 after step-down from 12 V to 3.3 V, while still being able to power OUT1 using 12 V if MOSFET is active)
- risks to stability of ESP32
- + and - connections of the MOSFET
- + and - connections of the Zener
  (recommendation was to plug in "anti-parallel" and close to the source of EMF kickback, being OUT1)

Legend:

- **IN1, OUT1** - barrel DC connectors; 1 is + and 2 is -; 12 V voltage
- **MOSF1** - logic-level N-channel MOSFET
- **ZENER_12V_1** - 12 V 5 W zener diode to eat "back EMF" signal coming from OUT1
- **POWER** - step-down switching converter from 12 V to 3.3 V
- **GATE1_RES** - 10 Ω resistor that avoids random gate state when device is booting, but low enough to support high-frequency PWM (10 kHz)

Notes:

- 12 V comes from a stable power supply, and it's not a car environment
- OUT1 should be able to handle about 2 A @ 12 V - it might be relevant to choosing right flyback diode

Comment: Missing decoupling capacitors. Please rotate your schematic and draw your relay, despite off-board, so we can see how you have connected it. What’s the coil current of your relay?

Comment: The components in text for would be nice. Now we have to read the FET type etc from an image and type it in to search for a data sheet. Maybe give a direct link to data sheet.

Comment: Pin 3: do not leave the EN pin floating. "To ensure that the power supply to the ESP32-C6 chip is stable during power-up, it is advised to add an RC delay circuit at the EN pin. The recommended setting for the RC delay circuit is usually R = 10 kΩ and C = 1 μF." - the datasheet.

Comment: @winny it's not a relay, it's a pulling magnet connected using 12V cable to OUT1

Comment: @AndrewMorton great catch, thank you

Comment: @underflow It does not matter someone said  relay instead of solenoid. What matters is the current which was asked.

Comment: the current will be about 2A (as in the post)

Comment: Able to handle is ambitious. By just reading the question, we don’t know your coil parameters. Please draw it as an RL. Please rotate your schematic.

Answer (score 0):

At least the zener makes no sense.

You have drawn a 1N5349 there. It is a 12V zener. It might make some sense if your solenoid supply voltage was less than 12V or the zener higher than 12V, but then there is no need for it to be a zener.

The zener will already conduct 100mA of current when there is 12V over it.

Better use something else than a 12V zener.

The choise of FET is also not great for driving it with 3.3V PWM signal. It has a rated VGS threshold of max 2.35V, but it might turn fully on at 3.3V. The VGS plateau is very near 4V, maybe 3.7V.

Comment: can you recommend how to choose a Schottky knowing 10kHz PWM, 2A@12V magnet?

Comment: @underflow It has to withstand 2A when it's on and average power based on PWM duty.

Comment: regarding the MOSFET, it's probably the best 3.3V logic-level one out there - I understand it would be a _bit_ more efficient when powered at higher voltage. in non-PWM mode it operates fine without heating - do you think that will change when used at PWM?

Comment: the device should be safe to operate 24/7, but some heating is accepted if it's within safe levels

Comment: across 1000s of Schottkys matching that, am I right to look for one with lowest switching time and lowest forward voltage?

Comment: @underflow I suggest using a 1N5004 diode and using an oscilloscope to see if there are any unfortunate voltage excursions - you can trigger the MOSFET with something cheaper than an ESP32 if you want, like a wire.

Comment: looks like 1N5820 will be a fit as well, it's cheap, popular and has a lot of publicity in different PWM-related topics :)

Comment: * I meant to write 1N5404